# Reading from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def avg_temp_march(f):
'''(file) -> float
Return the average temperature for the month of March
over all years in f.
'''

# We are providing the code for this function
# to illustrate one important difference between reading from a URL
# and reading from a regular file. When reading from a URL,
# we must first convert the line to a string.
# the str(line, 'ascii') conversion is not used on regular files.

march_temps = []

# read each line of the file and store the values
# as floats in a list
for line in f:
    line = str(line, 'ascii') # now line is a string
    temps = line.split()
    # there are some blank lines at the end of the temperature data
    # If we try to access temps[2] on a blank line,
    # we would get an error because the list would have no elements.
    # So, check that it is not empty.
    if temps != []:
        march_temps.append(float(temps[2]))

# calculate the average and return it
return sum(march_temps) / len(march_temps)
```

So I have this function given to me. you have to input a URL into it (the one I'm using is http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat) and it will read and convert into a string but the problem is it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    avg_temp_march(file)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\work\files.py", line 42, in avg_temp_march
    line = str(line, 'ascii') # now line is a string
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

My question is, why am I receiving this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call the function?

Comment: avg_temp_march("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat") or ill just do avg_temp_march(url) since I have a variable names url which already is the url itself

Comment: You're missing the step where you download the data under the URL. To do that you can use something like [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples).

Comment: So `f = 'robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat'`. What do you expect `for line in f:` to do??

Comment: Well I have code which writes the lines from the url to a text file and then I try to read from the text file when calling avg_temp_march but I still get an error                                                                                                                                                  
'code' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    avg_temp_march(input_month)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\108lab\files.py", line 46, in avg_temp_march
    line = str(line, 'ascii') # now line is a string
TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: What if you try line = line.decode(encoding='utf-8') instead?

Comment: You're assuming your line is a byte-like object. If you are in fact reading the data from a file before the loop why don't you just skip that line completely.

Comment: An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would go a long way to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after but this seems to do the trick. The main thing I was not sure about was what the input to `avg_temp_march` is. Is it a file, a list of strings, a url or something else?

It matters as you need to know how much processing is done before its called.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def avg_temp_march(f):
    march_temps = []

    # line does a lot it 
    # strips away new line and whitespace
    # decodes to utf-8
    # splits the values by space
    # does not include lines which are empty
    temps = [line.strip().decode(encoding='utf-8').split() for line in f if line != b'\n']

    # skip first 3 lines as they are not part of the actual data
    for t in temps[3:]:
        # take average temperatures for only march
        # the 3rd month at index 2
        march_temps.append(float(t[2]))

    return sum(march_temps) / len(march_temps)


f = urlopen("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/cryer2.dat")
print (avg_temp_march(f))
```

Let me know whats right/wrong about this and I can amend or delete as required.